# How to fix multiplication table using JOption Pane?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am trying to make a multiplication table with the user's input of the desired table and how many numbers he/she wants to display (for example the input of 2 for table and 5 for numbers would give 2,4,6,8,10).

I have tried the following but it wont give the desired output.

```
public class MultiplicationTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number."));

        int value = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of times."));

        printTable( num,  value);
    }

    private static void printTable(int num, int value) {
        int [] table = new int[value];
        for(int i = 0; i<=value-1; i++) {
            table[i] = num*i;
        }
        System.out.println(table); 
    }
}
```

It is printing: `[I@3d494fbf`
when it should be printing a multiplication table.

Answer (score 1):

Try `java.util.Arrays.toString(int[])` API.

Inside your `printTable()`, you can print like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(table));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `System.out.println` to print an object (like your array) what really happens is a call to the `toString` method of the object.

Now according to the [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method of the `Object` class:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

If you'd like to print the contents of the Array instead try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(table));`

Answer (score 0):

Put Print line inside loop
Like this:-

```
for(int i = 1; i<=value-1; i++)
{
    table[i] = num*i;
    System.out.println(table[i])
}
```

The Value '[I@3d494fbf' your program is printing is 'table' array memory path.